# Cannot access `istio-ingressgateway` when install istio on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I'm trying to install istio on my GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine)

I have done the following step

- enable `istio` when create cluster. Here is the verifcation when run `kubectl get deployment,svc -n istio-system`

```
kubectl get deployment,svc -n istio-system
NAME                                           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.extensions/cluster-local-gateway    1/1     1            1           5d21h
deployment.extensions/istio-citadel            1/1     1            1           5d22h
deployment.extensions/istio-galley             1/1     1            1           5d22h
deployment.extensions/istio-ingressgateway     1/1     1            1           5d22h
deployment.extensions/istio-pilot              1/1     1            1           5d22h
deployment.extensions/istio-policy             1/1     1            1           5d22h
deployment.extensions/istio-sidecar-injector   1/1     1            1           5d22h
deployment.extensions/istio-telemetry          1/1     1            1           5d22h
deployment.extensions/promsd                   1/1     1            1           5d22h

NAME                             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                                                                                      AGE
service/cluster-local-gateway    ClusterIP      10.0.1.88     <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP,31400/TCP,15011/TCP,8060/TCP,15030/TCP,15031/TCP                                                                              5d21h
service/istio-citadel            ClusterIP      10.0.13.49    <none>        8060/TCP,15014/TCP                                                                                                                           5d21h
service/istio-galley             ClusterIP      10.0.13.164   <none>        443/TCP,15014/TCP,9901/TCP                                                                                                                   5d21h
service/istio-ingressgateway     LoadBalancer   10.0.7.201    34.87.63.90   15020:30780/TCP,80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15029:32221/TCP,15030:31217/TCP,15031:32218/TCP,15032:31962/TCP,15443:32139/TCP   5d21h
service/istio-pilot              ClusterIP      10.0.11.239   <none>        15010/TCP,15011/TCP,8080/TCP,15014/TCP                                                                                                       5d21h
service/istio-policy             ClusterIP      10.0.3.193    <none>        9091/TCP,15004/TCP,15014/TCP                                                                                                                 5d21h
service/istio-sidecar-injector   ClusterIP      10.0.9.213    <none>        443/TCP                                                                                                                                      5d21h
service/istio-telemetry          ClusterIP      10.0.3.90     <none>        9091/TCP,15004/TCP,15014/TCP,42422/TCP                                                                                                       5d21h
service/promsd                   ClusterIP      10.0.3.213    <none>        9090/TCP                                                                                                                                     5d21h
```

- enable `sidecar` injection for my project namespace
  Here is output when run `kubectl get namespace -L istio-injection`

```
kubectl get namespace -L istio-injection
NAME              STATUS   AGE     ISTIO-INJECTION
default           Active   5d22h   enabled
ingress-nginx     Active   2d23h
istio-system      Active   5d22h   disabled
knative-serving   Active   5d22h
kube-public       Active   5d22h
kube-system       Active   5d22h
timeline          Active   5d20h   enabled
```

- restart `timeline` namespace service so that injection is enabled
  Here is output when run `kubectl get pod -n timeline`

```
kubectl get pod -n timeline
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
postgres-569db64f87-qwr82   2/2     Running   0          2d
prisma-5748bc8d8-729zq      2/2     Running   0          2d
prisma-5748bc8d8-kqqr9      2/2     Running   0          2d
prisma-5748bc8d8-r5cg2      2/2     Running   0          2d
redis-7df9bc8655-2tjck      2/2     Running   0          2d
redis-7df9bc8655-pvsrp      2/2     Running   0          2d
redis-7df9bc8655-vc6d8      2/2     Running   0          2d
timeline-779d79d4ff-gm4db   2/2     Running   0          2d
timeline-779d79d4ff-jg5zg   2/2     Running   0          2d
timeline-779d79d4ff-q5s9d   2/2     Running   0          2d
```

- setup `gateway` using

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: timeline-gateway
  namespace: timeline
spec:
  selector:
    app: timelline
    stage: production
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
```

- setup `virtualservice` using

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: timeline-virtualservice
  namespace: timeline
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - timeline-gateway
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: timeline
            port:
              number: 4000
```

Below is my `timeline` namespace `deployment` and `service` when run `kubectl get deployment,svc -n timeline`

```
kubectl get deployment,svc -n timeline
NAME                             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.extensions/postgres   1/1     1            1           4d10h
deployment.extensions/prisma     3/3     3            3           4d10h
deployment.extensions/redis      3/3     3            3           4d10h
deployment.extensions/timeline   3/3     3            3           4d10h

NAME               TYPE       CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/postgres   NodePort   10.0.15.150   <none>        5432:30714/TCP   4d10h
service/prisma     NodePort   10.0.8.32     <none>        4466:30480/TCP   4d10h
service/redis      NodePort   10.0.0.119    <none>        6379:31032/TCP   4d10h
service/timeline   NodePort   10.0.7.225    <none>        4000:31890/TCP   4d4h
```

The problem is I cannot access `istio-ingressgateway` always return `cannot be found` page`. I have verify my` timeline`service working with`ngix-ingress-controller` (see below image)

[image]

What is wrong with my setup? how can we make `istio` work?

I listed down all my `deployment` and `service` in all namespace below

```
kubectl get deployment,svc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE         NAME                                                             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
ingress-nginx     deployment.extensions/nginx-ingress-controller                   1/1     1            1           2d23h
istio-system      deployment.extensions/cluster-local-gateway                      1/1     1            1           5d22h
istio-system      deployment.extensions/istio-citadel                              1/1     1            1           5d22h
istio-system      deployment.extensions/istio-galley                               1/1     1            1           5d22h
istio-system      deployment.extensions/istio-ingressgateway                       1/1     1            1           5d22h
istio-system      deployment.extensions/istio-pilot                                1/1     1            1           5d22h
istio-system      deployment.extensions/istio-policy                               1/1     1            1           5d22h
istio-system      deployment.extensions/istio-sidecar-injector                     1/1     1            1           5d22h
istio-system      deployment.extensions/istio-telemetry                            1/1     1            1           5d22h
istio-system      deployment.extensions/promsd                                     1/1     1            1           5d22h
knative-serving   deployment.extensions/activator                                  1/1     1            1           5d22h
knative-serving   deployment.extensions/autoscaler                                 1/1     1            1           5d22h
knative-serving   deployment.extensions/cloudrun-controller                        1/1     1            1           5d22h
knative-serving   deployment.extensions/controller                                 1/1     1            1           5d22h
knative-serving   deployment.extensions/networking-istio                           1/1     1            1           5d22h
knative-serving   deployment.extensions/webhook                                    1/1     1            1           5d22h
kube-system       deployment.extensions/event-exporter-v0.2.5                      1/1     1            1           5d22h
kube-system       deployment.extensions/fluentd-gcp-scaler                         1/1     1            1           5d22h
kube-system       deployment.extensions/heapster-v1.6.1                            1/1     1            1           5d22h
kube-system       deployment.extensions/kube-dns                                   2/2     2            2           5d22h
kube-system       deployment.extensions/kube-dns-autoscaler                        1/1     1            1           5d22h
kube-system       deployment.extensions/l7-default-backend                         1/1     1            1           5d22h
kube-system       deployment.extensions/metrics-server-v0.3.1                      1/1     1            1           5d22h
kube-system       deployment.extensions/stackdriver-metadata-agent-cluster-level   1/1     1            1           5d22h
kube-system       deployment.extensions/tiller-deploy                              1/1     1            1           3d21h
timeline          deployment.extensions/postgres                                   1/1     1            1           4d11h
timeline          deployment.extensions/prisma                                     3/3     3            3           4d11h
timeline          deployment.extensions/redis                                      3/3     3            3           4d10h
timeline          deployment.extensions/timeline                                   3/3     3            3           4d10h

NAMESPACE         NAME                             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                                                                                                                                      AGE
default           service/kubernetes               ClusterIP      10.0.0.1      <none>           443/TCP                                                                                                                                      5d22h
ingress-nginx     service/ingress-nginx            LoadBalancer   10.0.7.136    35.240.157.212   80:32456/TCP,443:30484/TCP                                                                                                                   2d23h
istio-system      service/cluster-local-gateway    ClusterIP      10.0.1.88     <none>           80/TCP,443/TCP,31400/TCP,15011/TCP,8060/TCP,15030/TCP,15031/TCP                                                                              5d22h
istio-system      service/istio-citadel            ClusterIP      10.0.13.49    <none>           8060/TCP,15014/TCP                                                                                                                           5d22h
istio-system      service/istio-galley             ClusterIP      10.0.13.164   <none>           443/TCP,15014/TCP,9901/TCP                                                                                                                   5d22h
istio-system      service/istio-ingressgateway     LoadBalancer   10.0.7.201    34.87.63.90      15020:30780/TCP,80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15029:32221/TCP,15030:31217/TCP,15031:32218/TCP,15032:31962/TCP,15443:32139/TCP   5d22h
istio-system      service/istio-pilot              ClusterIP      10.0.11.239   <none>           15010/TCP,15011/TCP,8080/TCP,15014/TCP                                                                                                       5d22h
istio-system      service/istio-policy             ClusterIP      10.0.3.193    <none>           9091/TCP,15004/TCP,15014/TCP                                                                                                                 5d22h
istio-system      service/istio-sidecar-injector   ClusterIP      10.0.9.213    <none>           443/TCP                                                                                                                                      5d22h
istio-system      service/istio-telemetry          ClusterIP      10.0.3.90     <none>           9091/TCP,15004/TCP,15014/TCP,42422/TCP                                                                                                       5d22h
istio-system      service/promsd                   ClusterIP      10.0.3.213    <none>           9090/TCP                                                                                                                                     5d22h
knative-serving   service/activator-service        ClusterIP      10.0.0.5      <none>           80/TCP,81/TCP,9090/TCP                                                                                                                       5d22h
knative-serving   service/autoscaler               ClusterIP      10.0.12.217   <none>           8080/TCP,9090/TCP                                                                                                                            5d22h
knative-serving   service/controller               ClusterIP      10.0.13.31    <none>           9090/TCP                                                                                                                                     5d22h
knative-serving   service/webhook                  ClusterIP      10.0.2.121    <none>           443/TCP                                                                                                                                      5d22h
kube-system       service/default-http-backend     NodePort       10.0.15.7     <none>           80:30617/TCP                                                                                                                                 5d22h
kube-system       service/heapster                 ClusterIP      10.0.6.253    <none>           80/TCP                                                                                                                                       5d22h
kube-system       service/kube-dns                 ClusterIP      10.0.0.10     <none>           53/UDP,53/TCP                                                                                                                                5d22h
kube-system       service/metrics-server           ClusterIP      10.0.8.76     <none>           443/TCP                                                                                                                                      5d22h
kube-system       service/tiller-deploy            ClusterIP      10.0.3.125    <none>           44134/TCP                                                                                                                                    3d21h
timeline          service/postgres                 NodePort       10.0.15.150   <none>           5432:30714/TCP                                                                                                                               4d11h
timeline          service/prisma                   NodePort       10.0.8.32     <none>           4466:30480/TCP                                                                                                                               4d10h
timeline          service/redis                    NodePort       10.0.0.119    <none>           6379:31032/TCP                                                                                                                               4d10h
timeline          service/timeline                 NodePort       10.0.7.225    <none>           4000:31890/TCP                                                                                                                               4d5h
```

Updated: I add the istio-ingressgateway yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"Reconcile","app":"istio-ingressgateway","chart":"gateways","heritage":"Tiller","istio":"ingressgateway","k8s-app":"istio","kubernetes.io/cluster-service":"true","release":"istio"},"name":"istio-ingressgateway","namespace":"istio-system"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"status-port","port":15020,"targetPort":15020},{"name":"http2","nodePort":31380,"port":80,"targetPort":80},{"name":"https","nodePort":31390,"port":443},{"name":"tcp","nodePort":31400,"port":31400},{"name":"https-kiali","port":15029,"targetPort":15029},{"name":"https-prometheus","port":15030,"targetPort":15030},{"name":"https-grafana","port":15031,"targetPort":15031},{"name":"https-tracing","port":15032,"targetPort":15032},{"name":"tls","port":15443,"targetPort":15443}],"selector":{"app":"istio-ingressgateway","istio":"ingressgateway","release":"istio"},"type":"LoadBalancer"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2019-06-06T17:27:22Z"
  labels:
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    chart: gateways
    heritage: Tiller
    istio: ingressgateway
    k8s-app: istio
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    release: istio
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
  resourceVersion: "1523"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/istio-system/services/istio-ingressgateway
  uid: 580def22-8880-11e9-b69f-42010a940126
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.0.7.201
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: status-port
    nodePort: 30780
    port: 15020
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15020
  - name: http2
    nodePort: 31380
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    nodePort: 31390
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  - name: tcp
    nodePort: 31400
    port: 31400
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 31400
  - name: https-kiali
    nodePort: 32221
    port: 15029
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15029
  - name: https-prometheus
    nodePort: 31217
    port: 15030
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15030
  - name: https-grafana
    nodePort: 32218
    port: 15031
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15031
  - name: https-tracing
    nodePort: 31962
    port: 15032
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15032
  - name: tls
    nodePort: 32139
    port: 15443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15443
  selector:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
    release: istio
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 34.87.63.90
```

Updated 2: for the `prometheus` part. I have updated the `gateway` and `virtualservice` like below

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: timeline-gateway
  namespace: timeline
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
    - port:
        number: 15030
        name: https-prometheus
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
```

and

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: timeline-virtualservice
  namespace: timeline
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - timeline-gateway
  http:
    - match:
      - port: 80
      route:
        - destination:
            host: timeline
            port:
              number: 4000
    - match:
      - port: 15030
      route:
        - destination:
            host: promsd
            port:
              number: 9090
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the selectors of the gateway

```
spec:
  selector:
    app: timelline
    stage: production
```

Do they match with istio-ingressgateway pod's labels?

I suspect, you don't need `app: timelline`and `stage: production` selectors. Or it can be a simple typo -  timel**L**ine

So, try with following definition:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: timeline-gateway
  namespace: timeline
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
```

**Update:**
In order to expose additional port in the gateway you just need to add a bit of  definition for each port

```
- port:
      number: 15030
      name: https-prometheus
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

And also for HTTPS traffic, you'll need certificate and private key

```
tls:
  mode: SIMPLE # enables HTTPS on this port
  serverCertificate: /etc/certs/servercert.pem
  privateKey: /etc/certs/privatekey.pem
```

There is a very good example in the official Istio documentation - 
https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/gateway/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. you're right, after deleted the `app` and `stage` from the `gateway`, i'm able to access `istio-ingressgateway` at port `80`. so in order for the `gateway` to work we need `gateway` `selector` matchs with `istio-ingressgateway` `selector`? One more question how can we make other port in `istio-ingressgateway` work also (`grafana`, `prometheus`,`kiali`...)? I have added `istio-ingressgateway` `yaml` for reference

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh `so in order for the gateway to work we need gateway selector matchs with istio-ingressgateway selector?` - **Yes** Also, I've updated my answer for the second part of your question.

Comment: hi for the `prometheus` part i have updated question the last part. (can see new `gateway` and `virtualservice` yaml). There's something wrong with the configuration (cannot access `prometheus` at port `15030`

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh but can you access prometheus internaly on port 9090? inside the mesh?

Comment: Hi i can access `promsd` on port 9090 (by using `port-forwarding` from the console)

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh try to go with `host: promsd.istio-system.svc.cluster.local` instead of `host: promsd` in VirtualService definition.

Comment: thanks that work perfectly. my wonder is there template or config yaml file that expose all those instead of manually? (grafana, promsd, kiali...)?

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh look at helm with chart templates. Also please accept the answer if it was helpful ;)

Comment: thanks done accept answer. i've look at helm chart for istio but seem there is no chart for exposing these service. any link for these template?